# wrting integers as 4 bytes to file java

Tags: java, file-io

I am writing a java program in which I have to write all integers to a file. To make it more efficient I just want to write int as only 4 bytes(which I think will be a binary file kind of thing, but I am not sure) and while reading back from the file I just want to read the integers directly(I do not want to read bytes and then convert them to integer).
Is there a way to do that.

I want to write millions of integers to the file I want the method to be fast and efficient.

I am new to this so please put up with me.

Comment: So you want to write bytes, but read integers? That makes no sense. You will have to read the bytes to retrieve your integer

Comment: And this is by no means ”more efficient”

Comment: What he probably means is, he doesn't want to deal with putting the int back together from the 4 bytes. Good news is, that for every function that writes an int as bytes, there's a corresponding function to read the bytes as int again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `DataOutputStream` class or a `RandomAccessFile`. Both provide methods for writing structured binary data, for example the "int as 4 bytes" you want.

Comment: This is good. But is there a way to make these read writes buffered. I checked out `bufferedwriter` and it only support writing and reading bytes

Comment: No chance for buffered IO with the `RandomAccessFile`, but you can add a buffer to the stream approach by putting a `BufferedOutputStream` between the `DataOutputStream` and the `FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score 6):

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("numbers.dat");
 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
 dos.writeInt(my_int);
 dos.flush();
 dos.close();
```

If you want to have the data buffered wrap the file stream in to a buffered stream as below:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("numbers.dat");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(myIntVlaue).array();
```

Comment: I suppose that's one of the more complicated ways to do it.